# API access to Knowledge article content inline images

Tags: api, callout, knowledge

I am using following code to access and save locally an SFDC inline image, but it does not work.  i add the oauthHeader.
I am getting the oauthHeader as :

oauthHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + oauth2Response.access_token);

Can you help how do i fetch and save the image from the SFDC?

```
public void fetchImage(Header oauthHeader) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

    String source_url="https://c.na32.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka438000000GtBG&feoid=00N00000008rk2N&refid=0EM38000000HYPi";

    String imageName="NavTestImage.png";

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(source_url);
    httpGet.addHeader(oauthHeader);
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(imageName));
            int inByte;
            while((inByte = is.read()) != -1)
                 fos.write(inByte);
            is.close();
            fos.close();
        }

}
```

Comment: Please add more details. are you facing issue? what is your question?